# No redirect URL in page headers. How to follow redirect. HttpClient 4

Tags: java, redirect, header, httpclient

I'm trying to test if the following page http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console-freeze/screen-freeze-wizard. The page redirects to http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console-freeze/screen-freeze-solution however that is not shown in the header.

My app checks page URLs status', what's the best/fastest way to follow this redirect and check if it ends up in a 404 or 200.

Edit: When I use fiddler2 to check the pages header I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: -1
Location: /en-US/xbox-360/console-freeze/screen-freeze-solution
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 03 Sep 2012 15:14:16 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Which gives the redirect. My code is as follows

```
public void status() {

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpHead hh = new HttpHead("http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console-freeze/screen-freeze-wizard");
    System.out.println("Requesting : " + hh.getURI());

    try {
        HttpResponse response = hc.execute(hh);
        System.out.println("Protocol : " + response.getProtocolVersion());
        System.out.println("Status code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        Header [] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
        for (Header header : headers) {
          System.out.println(" --> " + header.getName() + ":" + header.getValue());
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

But it only gives the following response:

```
Requesting : http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/console-freeze/screen-freeze-wizard
Protocol : HTTP/1.1
Status code : 404
 --> Cache-Control:private
 --> Content-Length:0
 --> X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
 --> Date:Mon, 03 Sep 2012 15:23:59 GMT
 --> Connection:keep-alive
...complete.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your request is identical to the request that your browser makes, you can guarantee that you will get the same response. I would try checking the other headers that your browser sends and see if you can make your java application send the same ones.

Answer (score 0):

It seems fiddler2 uses a HttpGet request and just reads the headers. So by changing to that in my code I was able to get the correct response I was looking for.